# Reputation difference chat vs. normal

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I had a chat session with @badp just the other day. Afterwards I noticed the following difference:

**Chat**
[image]
**Normal**
[image]

Does a mathematical relation exist between the two ((2*normal)+10...haha)? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number appears to be your total [StackExchange network reputation](http://stackexchange.com/users/1669259/jacob-jan-tuinstra?tab=accounts) rather than your WebApps reputation. Meanwhile, badges are only shown from accounts with more than 200 points. This is similar to the rules for [Flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/1669259/jacob-jan-tuinstra?tab=flair), except since you need a minimum of 20 points to chat I guess it counts them all.

See also [this meta SO discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77716/total-reputation-is-different-in-chat-and-flair).

Comment: yeah, it's the network rep